# Call polymorphic function from vector of pointer to base class

Tags: c++, class, vector, polymorphism

I have a structure of classes that looks like:

```
      1
     / \
    2   3
   |||  ||
  4 5 6 7 8
```

and a vector that holds pointers to 1. 1 has three pure virtual functions, all of which are overridden to return default values in 2 and 3 then specific ones in 4 through 8.

The vector is controlled through a class and the two offending functions:

```
class Vector
{

public:
    Vector();

    void vectorAdd(Food* food)
    {
        mList.push_back(food);
    }


    //The two offending functions. The functions they point to are pure
    //virtual in the Food class and overridden in the derived classes.

    string getDescription(size_t index)
    {
        return mList[index]->getDescription();
    }


    double getPrice(size_t index)
    {
        return mList[index]->getPrice();
    }
private:
    vector<Food*> mList;
};
```

I'm adding to the vector from int main by:

```
list.vectorAdd(&Spaghetti);
```

The code all compiles, but whenever I call Vector::getDescription(index) or Vector::getPrice(index) I get a Debug Error with no information as to what went wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't `getDescription` be `getDescription()`, and ditto for `getPrice`?

Comment: I guarantee you that your code does *not* compile, contrary to your assertion.

Comment: It does compile, and I just forgot to put those parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your `vectorAdd` function argument should be of type `Food*`, rather than `*Food`.

```
void vectorAdd(Food* pFood)
{
    mList.push_back(pFood);
}
```

Comment: That was just me mistyping since I was stupid didn't copy and paste my code. It wouldn't compile the way it is in that, will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, needed to use (new...) instead of (&...)